# How do I figure out which side is easier to manipulate?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I just stumbled a "prove by induction" question and the answer says we should start with the RHS since it is easier to manipulate and I'm wondering if there is any techniques/Rules/ways to figure out which side is easier or likely to be easier to manipulate?

From this question I've taken that it is easier to manipulate a polynomial over a fraction but generally what other ways or rules are there?

$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n-1}$$

Comment: In this example, it's definitely easier to start with the right-hand side because that changes in a very predictable way as $n$ changes. (Namely, we simply append another term.) By contrast, $\frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}$ doesn't change in any particularly obvious neat way as $n$ changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be very unsatisfying, but the answer (IMHO) to the question *"How can I see which side is easier to manimulate?"* is this:
$$\mathbf{\text{Experience}}.$$

There is no general rule that tells you which side will be easier to manipulate. How could there be, when it is nearly impossible to formulate a good unambiguous definition of *easy*.

Comment: That's definately right but I wanted some general feedback from you the people's experience. Sometimes there are things you have noticed from you experience you can pass down to me without me needing to go through it all? If that makes sense?

Comment: That's definitely true, but way too broad a question in general. If you can narrow it down, then you have fine question. For instance: *"When proving by induction, is it wiser to start manipulating polynomials or rational functions and why?"* Something like this is a fine question to get an insight into the experience of other mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove $$\frac {x^n-1}{x-1} = 1+x+x^2+...+x^n$$ by induction, it is easier to start at RHS because it clearly shows that you only need to add x^[n+1} t0 both sides and use the induction hypotheses.

In general, it depends on the question.

There is no black and white rule that works all the time.